# How to create a dropdown list inside a table?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with a button in each row that when you click on it this allows you edit the content of the cells. My question is that two cells must be a dropdownlist, when I click on the button and the dropdown must show the data I have stored.
The columns that must be dropdowns are Name Values and Address Values.

How can I do it?
Here is my code:

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.Spokes)
{
   <tr id="hoverable">                                        
     <td>@item.Id</td>
     <td><div class="row_data">@item.Name</div></td>
     <td><div class="row_data">@item.Address</div></td>
   </tr> 
}
```

Comment: Maybe https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ library will help you(check inline mode).

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for your issue :

1. Use Jquery or javascript DOM to replace the content of your cells by
               DropdowList when you click on the edit button
2. Foreach records duplicate the rows ( one for showing data and other for edit) : when you click on the edit button hide the first row and show the second row that contain dropdown list